# Geo Distance Filter with ElasticSearch always returns 0 results

Tags: elasticsearch, geo

I am using the [Geo Distance Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-filter.html) with [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org) and no matter what distance I search for, elasticsearch 0.90.11 returns zero results.

Here's what I did: First, delete/create a new index with the geo mapping:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/photos'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/photos' -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "pin" : {
        "properties" : {
            "location" : {
                "type" : "geo_point"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Then, add a document:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/photos/photo?pretty=1' -d '
{
   "pin" : {
      "location" : {
         "lat" : 46.8,
         "lon" : -71.2
      }
   },
   "file" : "IMG_2115.JPG"
}
'
```

Then search:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/photos/_search?pretty=1&size=20' -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "match_all" : {}
   },
   "filter" : {
      "geo_distance" : {
         "distance" : "10km",
         "pin.location" : {
            "lat" : "46.8",
            "lon" : "-71.2"
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

But the search yields zero hits:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Anyone know why it didn't find the document within the radius? As an interesting side note, the "filtered" syntax having both "query" and "filter" as subfields as described in the document referenced above seems to no longer work at all, seems like now "query" and "filter" need to be at the top level of the json query.

Any help appreciated ...

Answer (score 6):

Turns out that the offical manual page is not accurate, the mapping needs to be

```
[Sun Feb  9 11:01:55 2014] # Request to: http://localhost:9200
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/photos?pretty=1' -d '
{
   "mappings" : {
      "photo" : {
         "properties" : {
            "Location" : {
               "type" : "geo_point"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

and the records with the GPS data then need to be added like this:

```
[Sun Feb  9 11:01:56 2014] # Request to: http://localhost:9200
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/photos/photo?pretty=1' -d '
{
   "file" : "/home/mschilli/iphone/IMG_2115.JPG",
   "Location" : [
      46.8,
      -71.2
   ]
}
'
```

Then later the query

```
[Sun Feb  9 11:05:00 2014] # Request to: http://localhost:9200
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/photos/_search?pretty=1&size=100' -d '
{
   "filter" : {
      "geo_distance" : {
         "distance" : "1km",
         "Location" : [
            36.986,
            -121.443333333333
         ]
      }
   },
   "query" : {
      "match_all" : {}
   }
}
'
```

will show the desired result, correctly filtering out results outside the selected GPS distance.

Comment: +1 thank you! I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days.

Comment: I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/15745) to update the misleading docs.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem and spent lot of time to solve it. So maybe it can be helpful to someone. 
The problem may be that if you want search by distance on nested filed property like:

`something:
  properties:
    name:
      type: text
   city: 
      type: nested
      properties:
         location: 
           type: geo_point`

You need add nested query inside main query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html